# Remove default.aspx from the root site MOSS url

Tags: site-collection

When we request our root SharePoint MOSS site, we see a redirect to default.aspx. Is it possible to change this within MOSS to just show the domain name and not append default.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this blog post from Waldek Mastykarz on using IIS 7 Url Rewrite module to create semantic URLs:  http://blog.mastykarz.nl/friendly-urls-sharepoint-site-4-steps-iis7-url-rewrite-module/